# Type 1 and Type 2 error with a decision rule with a discrete distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider the discrete distribution below:

| X | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $p_0$ | $a_0$ | $a_1$ | $a_2$ | $a_3$ | $a_4$ | $a_5$ | $a_6$ |
| $p_1$ | $b_0$ | $b_1$ | $b_2$ | $b_3$ | $b_4$ | $b_5$ | $b_6$ |

Suppose $H_0: p_0$ is the correct distribution, and $H_a: p_1$ is the correct distribution.

We have the decision rule to reject $H_0$ if $X \leq 2$.

How would we find the type 1 and type 2 error?

Since a Type 1 error is the probability of rejecting $H_0$ when it is actually true,  I believe the probability of type 1 error with this decision rule  is $a_0 + a_1 + a_2$.

Since a Type 2 error is the probability of not rejecting $H_0$ when it is actually false, I believe the probability of type 2 error with this decision rule is $b_3 + b_4 + b_5 + b_6$.

Comment: looks good to me